# Android image gallery is very slow

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gallery, photo-gallery

I'm starting with android and following some tutorials on web. I'm trying to create an android gallery image and it works, but only if the image that i put in drawable folder are small. If i put inside it images with a bigger size and better quality my gallery go really slow.What i have to do?

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}



// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {



        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

Thanks to everyone that will help me.

Comment: `I'm trying to create an android gallery image`. What do you mean by that? There is no gallery. There is only a Gallery app.

Comment: I mean that I want create a grid with some images and my app goes very slow when I use high quality images that I put in drawable folder.

Comment: add to the Manifest

android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: are you loading your images in the same thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u simply need to load thumbnail of these images and load them into the gird,read more on creating and caching tumbnails on internet and tutorials.and when user clicks that thumbnail i.e particular grid position then you should load the original image and display it.give a try at picasso library,would help you out

Answer (score 1):

welcome to android world.

You should try using `ViewHolder` pattern.

Please take a look at this tutorial.

[good tutorial for viewholder pattern](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/smooth-out-your-listviews-with-a-viewholder/9)